# Nontrivial solution for $x^2y''−axy'+ay=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the largest of the numbers $a∈\Bbb{R}$ at which there is a nontrivial solution of the equation $$x^2y''−axy'+ay=0, $$  limited on the interval $[1,+∞)$ .

My answer: $a=2$. Let's make the characteristic equation of the differential equation $$x^2b^2−axb+a=0, $$
where discriminant is $D=a^2x^2-4ax^2. $

$b_1,b_2=(ax+sqrt(a^2x^2-4ax^2))/x^2 >=1 . $

Solving this we have $a<=2.$ max of $a$ is $2.$

Comment: Thanks for the question... What have you tried? What are your thoughts about the problem?

Comment: I've got the solution like $y(x) = c_1 x^a + c_2 x$. but no idea what to do next

Comment: Hmm, doesn't that imply that there are nontrivial solutions for *any* value of $a$? Or am I missing something? It's not quite clear what you mean by "limited on the interval $[1,+\infty)$".

Comment: Do you mean BOUNDED on the interval $[1,\infty)$? In which case, the answer is that there are no such solutions for $a>0$. [But there is a solution for $a=0$, namely $y=$ const.. Or if you regard that as trivial, then there is a solution for any negative $a$.]

Comment: This is a [cauchy-euler equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-Euler_equation), you need to make a change of variable to go from $x^2y''−axy'+ay=0$ to $z''−(a-1)z'+az=0$ and then solve looking at the characteristic equation, hope it  helps